# Use parameter in jmeter report filename

Tags: parameters, report, jmeter

I have a summary report as part of a reusable module in jmeter and would like to parameterize the output file name of this report, so that I have my own report for each of my ThreadGroups/Tests.

The testplan looks like this:

[image]

this is the summary report:

[image]

In my Test ThreadGroups I set the property `testName` in a BeanShell sampler:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
JMeterUtils.setProperty("testName", "test1");
```

The print testName sampler looks like this:

```
print(props.get("testName"));
```

and correctly prints the following to the console:

```
test1
test2
```

But I only get one output report named `results/test2/report.jtl` that includes all results.

---

It gets even weirder when I run jmeter in the non-GUI mode (`-n`), because the output will be saved to: `results/1/report.jtl`

Answer (score 0):

Quote from http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html:

> Properties are not the same as variables. Variables are local to a
>   thread; properties are common to all threads, and need to be
>   referenced using the __P or __property function.

So you have to put the test name into a variable, not into a property.

Comment: when I use ${testName} as placeholder in the report, the folder is called: results/${testName}, so it is not interpreted at all.